# In zend framework, is there any way to interact between different modules?

Tags: api, zend-framework

I have got three modules in my zend application.

--module1
--module2
--module3

Here module3 is an api module. It doesn't have any views.
module1 and module2 should interact with module3(api module) to get the needed data.
module1 and module2 will have custom controller logic and views.
Is there any way to enable this kind of communication. I am new to zend framework. 
Any help in this regard will be well appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the API you should create a Service layer for. Then if you need to expose this API externally you can use Module 1 to act as an intermediary between "remote" clients, but the other two modules can use the Service layer directly.

Comment: @prodigitalson: Thank you for your answer. You have directed me in the right direction.:)

Comment: @prodigitalson: Can you provide me with any reference, it would be really helpful